# Error while running dnu restore : The AddressFamily 117 is not valid for the System.Net.IPEndPoint end point, use InterNetwork instead

Tags: c#, linux, nuget, dnx, dnvm

I am trying to run a .NET program on linux  using dnx.

OS: centos 7

I have both mono and coreclr installed and dnvm is able to switch between the two. the version is 1.0.0-beta7-12264.

I tried to execute a simple Hello World program and ran dnu restore to download the dependencies.

However it throws an error AddressFamily 117 is not valid for IPendpoint. I tried to swithh to http:// version of nuget instead of https but that didn't solve the problem.

This is the  error output

> Restoring packages for /home/ganesh/Development/test/project.json
>   GET http://www.nuget.org/api/v2/   GET
>   http://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Console'
>   Warning: FindPackagesById: System.Console   The AddressFamily 117 is
>   not valid for the System.Net.IPEndPoint end point, use InterNetwork
>   instead. Parameter name: socketAddress   GET
>   http://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Console'
>   Warning: FindPackagesById: System.Console   The AddressFamily 117 is
>   not valid for the System.Net.IPEndPoint end point, use InterNetwork
>   instead. Parameter name: socketAddress   GET
>   http://www.nuget.org/api/v2/FindPackagesById()?id='System.Console'
>   Error: FindPackagesById: System.Console   The AddressFamily 117 is not
>   valid for the System.Net.IPEndPoint end point, use InterNetwork
>   instead. Parameter name: socketAddress
>   ---------- System.ArgumentException: The AddressFamily 117 is not valid for the System.Net.IPEndPoint end point, use InterNetwork
>   instead. Parameter name: socketAddress    at
>   System.Net.IPEndPoint.Create(SocketAddress socketAddress)    at
>   System.Net.Dns.TryGetAddrInfo(String name, AddressInfoHints flags,
>   IPHostEntry& hostinfo)    at System.Net.Dns.TryGetAddrInfo(String
>   name, IPHostEntry& hostinfo)    at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String
>   name)    at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName,
>   Boolean includeIPv6)    at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String
>   hostNameOrAddress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the coreclr doesn't support restoring packages yet. dnu restore has to be run under mono and then we can switch to coreclr for dnx execution

I encountered the timeout issue in mono too but it got resolved on its own after trying for 4-5 times.

https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab/issues/147